# Open and closed operators.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I was wondering whether there is a general methodology of going about showing whether bounded, linear operators are open mappings or closed operators? Let's say I meet a space and an operator such as the weighted right-shift.

$T : ℓ^
1
(\mathbb{N}) → ℓ^
1
(\mathbb{N}),   T(x_1, x_2, x_3 . . .) = (x_2,
x_3/
2
,
x_4
/(2^
2)
, . . .).$

Is there some fixed way of doing this kind of problem? I know that you have to use the open mapping and the closed graph theorem, but it is not clear to me, for example, how to show that the domain of $T$ is a closed subset of $ℓ^1$

Comment: What do you mean?  What's an open operator?  The domain of your $T$ is all of  $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$ because you said $T: \ell^1(\mathbb N) \to \ell^1(\mathbb N)$.

Comment: Sorry, I mean open mapping, edited the question.

Comment: It seems you have the tools you need. If you want to show a bounded linear operator is open, then the open mapping theorem says you just need to show your operator is surjective. If you want to show the operator is closed, in the sense its graph is closed, then the closed graph theorem says you need to show your operator is continuous (which is equivalent to being bounded in a normed vector space).